# How to delete a AWS waf IP-sets IP using CLI command?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, devops, amazon-waf

Im trying to delete a aws waf IP-SETS IP using CLI cmd.

im using this cmd.

```
aws waf delete-ip-set --name PROD-IP-SUSPECTS --scope REGIONAL ap-south-1
```

im getting this error.

usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]

```
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: --ip-set-id, --change-token
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `--name` is not in the Synopsis from aws cli docs. You can try `aws waf delete-ip-set --ip-set-id <value> --change-token <value>`

Follow this docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/waf/delete-ip-set.html

Comment: --change-token means what value need to add ?
now im getting this error: An error occurred (WAFNonexistentItemException) when calling the DeleteIPSet operation: The referenced item does not exist

this is current code.
'aws waf delete-ip-set --ip-set-id aa1f93bd-4eda-4ac7-9b40-4e82c5068a06 --change-token aa1f93bd-4eda-4ac7-9b40-4e82c5068a06'

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below commands to use it in your case

```
    [ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf get-change-token
{
    "ChangeToken": "77f566dc-f188-4104-a485-74b9702f3704"
}
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf create-ip-set --name ipset1111 --change-token 77f566dc-f188-4104-a485-74b9702f3704
{
    "IPSet": {
        "IPSetId": "130056e7-32e9-4b44-8f16-a8116221edd4",
        "Name": "ipset1111",
        "IPSetDescriptors": []
    },
    "ChangeToken": "77f566dc-f188-4104-a485-74b9702f3704"
}
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf list-ip-sets
{
    "IPSets": [
        {
            "IPSetId": "130056e7-32e9-4b44-8f16-a8116221edd4",
            "Name": "ipset1111"
        }
    ]
}
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf delete-ip-set --ip-set-id 130056e7-32e9-4b44-8f16-a8116221edd4 --change-token 77f566dc-f188-4104-a485-74b9702f3704

An error occurred (WAFStaleDataException) when calling the DeleteIPSet operation: The input token is no longer current.
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf get-change-token
{
    "ChangeToken": "62ade59c-db73-4cb1-b6e6-318e23553b99"
}
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-249 ~]$ aws waf delete-ip-set --ip-set-id 130056e7-32e9-4b44-8f16-a8116221edd4 --change-token 62ade59c-db73-4cb1-b6e6-318e23553b99
{
    "ChangeToken": "62ade59c-db73-4cb1-b6e6-318e23553b99"
}
```

- aws waf get-change-token : to get change token
- aws waf create-ip-set : to create ip set
- aws waf list-ip-sets : to list ip sets

In the docs, they mention this

> Permanently deletes an IPSet . You can’t delete an IPSet if it’s still
> used in any Rules or if it still includes any IP addresses.
>
> If you just want to remove an IPSet from a Rule , use UpdateRule .
>
> To permanently delete an IPSet from AWS WAF, perform the following
> steps:
>
> ```
> Update the IPSet to remove IP address ranges, if any. For more information, see UpdateIPSet .
>
> Use GetChangeToken to get the change token that you provide in the ChangeToken parameter of a DeleteIPSet request.
>
> Submit a DeleteIPSet request.
> ```